# array_push not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-push

`print_r($members)` coming like this following result

```
Array ( [myname] => Array ( [userid] => 52 [age] => 46 )
Array ( [hisname] => Array ( [userid] => 22 [age] => 47 )
Array ( [yourname] => Array ( [userid] => 47 [age] => 85 )
```

`array_push()` push not working in the `foreach` loop

```
foreach($members as $key => $item){
  // print "<br>" . $key ."<br>";
  array_push($members, '$key');
}
```

The result expecting like this  following code with the `array_push()`

```
Array ( [myname] => Array ( [userid] => 52 [age] => 46 [0] => myname)
Array ( [hisname] => Array ( [userid] => 22 [age] => 47 [0] => hisname)
Array ( [yourname] => Array ( [userid] => 47 [age] => 85 [0] => yourname)
```

**result**

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 126

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 126

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 126

Comment: And what is the output result? Ans what is `$arr` in your foreach?

Comment: That _warning_ comes because you do not initialize `$arr` as an (empty) array. Place this before the loop: `$arr=[];`. No idea why that happens in _all_ iterations though...

Comment: Oh, and: `'$key'` pushes the _literal_ string "$key" onto the array, not the _content_ of that variable.

Comment: Now you've changed the code in the question, and it seems that you are pushing data into `$members`, the same array which you are iterating. That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes that is what I need to see in the end result. Create new array which should be the key. Hope you understand the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$arr` does not seems to be an array. Change your code to,

```
foreach($members as $key => $item){
   array_push($members[$key], $key); //or $members[$key][] = $key;
}
```